# After marrying a US citizen, can my US immigration visa be processed in my country of temporary residence?

Tags: usa, visa, immigration, marriage, pakistani-citizen

I am a Pakistani national, a Master's student in Sweden for quite some time. I will be done with my studies in the beginning of 2020. I reside on a study residence permit from Swedish immigration agency.

I am getting married in January 2019, my fiancée is a US citizen living in the US. After we marry, am I allowed to file my case for immigration to the US here in Sweden or would I have to go back to Pakistan to submit it? If I am allowed, I would like to know some info about the processing time for this visa processing from Sweden.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can file in Sweden since you reside there.  Unfortunately I do not know how long the processing time might be.

Comment: https://se.usembassy.gov/visas/immigrant-visas/fiancee-visa/ has some details. The interview section says the interview could happen up to a month after the date of approval notice, and later states "most administrative processing is resolved within 60 days of the visa interview." I guess if there are complications, they could extend the processing time outside these frames.

Comment: @tripleee thanks for the link. If you post it in an answer and ping me here, I'll upvote it.

Comment: I don't pretend to have enough knowledge about this, but feel free to import this into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can file your immigration application anywhere in the world. 
Additionally, you don't necessarily have to wait to get married in order to apply for green card.Instead, your fiancée can apply a K1 fiancé visa for you, so that you can come in U.S before you start applying for green card. K1 application needs about 4-7months to get adjudicated.

However, if you will get married in January 2019, your I130 needs about 1 year to get adjudicated.